# Magento setPrice is not work with catalog_block_product_list_collection event?

Tags: magento

This is my config code.

```
<catalog_block_product_list_collection>
            <observers>
                <smashingmagazine_logproductupdate>
                    <class>smashingmagazine_logproductupdate/observer</class>
                    <method>listingchange</method>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                </smashingmagazine_logproductupdate>
            </observers>
        </catalog_block_product_list_collection>
```

This is my function.

```
public function listingchange(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();

    foreach ($collection as $product)
    {
       $product->setPrice( 1500 );
    }

}
```

price get in list.phtml file price code is.

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
```

The setPrice() is not work. getPrice() function is work fine.

but setPrice() is not work.

please help. thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would better try to do that using `catalog_product_collection_load_after` event with :

```
public function listingchange(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();

    if ($collection->count()>0){
        $collection->walk(array($this, '_manageProduct'));
    }
}

public function _manageProduct($product) {
    $product->setFinalPrice( 1500 );
}
```

It works really nice for me...

Comment: setFinalPrice(1500) instead ?